# How do I set the dialect for a SQLAlchemy connection pool with PostgreSQL in Django Python? Needed for pre-ping feature enabled

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

### What I'm trying to achieve

I need to activate the pre-ping feature for as SQLAlchemy db pool in Django Python.

### Error

When I set the `pre_ping` property to `True`, I get the following error which says I need to pass a `dialect` to the connection pool when using the pre-ping feature:

```
The ping feature requires that a dialect is passed to the connection pool.
```

### Code

Code for the connection pool creator/handler:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import traceback
from myproject import settings
from dataClasses.EmptyObject import *
import json
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool

dbPool = None

class DbPoolHelper:

    def ensurePoolCreated(self):
        global dbPool
        if dbPool != None:
            return
            
        self.createPool()

    def dbConnect(self):
        dbConfig = self.getDbPoolConfig()
        dbConnection = psycopg2.connect(user=dbConfig.user, password=dbConfig.password, dbname=dbConfig.dbName, host=dbConfig.host, port=dbConfig.port)
        print("=========== POOL CONNECTED =================")
        return dbConnection

    def createPool(self):
        dbConnection = self.dbConnect
        global dbPool
        dbPool = pool.QueuePool(dbConnection, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5, pre_ping=True)
        print("=========== POOL CREATED =================")

    def execute(self, sql, sqlParams):
        try:
            global dbPool
            self.ensurePoolCreated()
            poolConnection = dbPool.connect()
            cursor = poolConnection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, sqlParams)
            poolConnection.commit()
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            poolConnection.close()
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return e

    def getDbPoolConfig(self):
        settingName = "pool"
        dbConfig = EmptyObject()
        dbConfig.host = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["HOST"]
        dbConfig.port = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PORT"]
        dbConfig.user = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["USER"]
        dbConfig.password = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PASSWORD"]
        dbConfig.dbName = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["NAME"]
        dbConfig.poolSize = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["POOL_SIZE"]
        dbConfig.poolMaxOverflow = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["POOL_MAX_OVERFLOW"]
        dbConfig.poolRecycleTime = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["POOL_RECYCLE_TIME"]

        return dbConfig
```

### Question

How do I pass this `dialect` to the connection pool when using a PostgreSQL database?

### Other notes

In case you know another way of creating a connection pool with the pre-ping feature enabled, those suggestions are welcome too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`QueuePool`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool) constructor passes all keyword arguments to the [`Pool`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.Pool) constructor. This constructor supports the `dialect` argument. So you should be able to add a dialect to your `QueuePool` call:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
# redacted
dbPool = pool.QueuePool(dbConnection, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5, pre_ping=True, dialect=postgresql.dialect())
# redacted
```